# Error serializing data greater than 2GB in Dask

Tags: python, pickle, dask, dask-distributed

I'm using Dask with some large intermediate values and I'm getting errors from pickle like the following:

```
error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

What's going on?  Does Dask not support serializing chunks of data greater than 2GB?

Answer (score 3):

Dask sometimes uses the Pickle and Cloudpickle libraries for serializing data.  In Python 2 Pickle has a 2GB limit.  There are a few solutions to this problem:

#### Use Smaller Chunks

You may want to decrease your chunksize to pass around bits of data that are smaller than 2GB each.  This can help your performance as well.  2GB chunks are fairly big for most applications today.  I personally tend to shoot for chunk sizes closer to 100MB.

In dask.dataframe you can usually control chunk size when you read in your data, such as with the `blocksize=` keyword in `dd.read_csv` (although different data ingestion methods will have different ways of doing this).

Alternatively you can repartition your data.

```
df = df.repartition(npartitions=1000)
```

#### Define custom serializers

Dask doesn't have to use Pickle, and indeed it often doesn't for special data types like NumPy arrays.  See the following documentation for how to register your own serialization function:

http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/serialization.html

#### Use Python 3

Python 2 is nearing end of life.  Now may be a convenient time to consider starting to use Python 3 for which many problems like this simply go away.  Most community libraries now support Python 3 as well or better than they support Python 2.

Of course, switching can be a challenge, especially for large enterprise codebases, so the other options above may suffice in the short term.